# Editing value in NSTableView results in error

Tags: objective-c, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I have an `NSTableView` whose column's values are bound to an `NSArrayController`. The problem is, when a user tries to edit values in the table (all the columns are editable), the program throws this error:

```
-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object
```

Anyone know how I can prevent this from happening? I can implement my own sloppy editor that will give the user a couple `NSTextFields` to create a new object for the `NSArrayController` whilst deleting the old one, but it would be much preferred if I could get this to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your table view's data stored in an `NSDictionary`, by any chance? Based on the error, it looks as though when the user edits a value, your code is attempting to set the new value on a key in an `NSDictionary`, like so:

```
myDict[@"aKey"] = newValue;
```

But this is impossible, since instances of `NSDictionary` are immutable. You could try using an `NSMutableDictionary` instead.

Comment: Where can I see/change this? When looking at my `NSArrayController` in the Attributes Inspector, under Object Controller, the Class Name is set as `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: That's just a claim you're making to IB. The claim is not reality. The actual model is presumably something you create in code. To what is the array controller's content binding bound?

Comment: @KenThomases The controller's not bound to anything. I've got a reference outlet hooked up to it and I edit it (and thus the table) using `addObject` and `removeObjectAt...`. Should I instead have it bound to an `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableDisctionary`'s?

Comment: What kind of objects are you passing to `-[NSArrayController addObject:]`?

Comment: @KenThomases `NSMutableDictionary`'s for the most part, but there are a few that could be `NSDictionary`'s. Is the solution simply to convert the `NSDictionary`'s to their mutable counterparts before throwing them in?

Comment: @KenThomases Just ran some tests and not only did that fix this problem, but several as well. Thank you thank you thank you!! You've concluded about two hours of debugging. Please submit your comment as an answer so I can properly award you your points.

Comment: I would say that Alex got the right answer. I just clarified. Glad you got things working.